# PHP to display simple LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I joined (LEFT OUTER JOIN) two tables (user and userrole) to display a list of four fields (three from `user`, one from `userrole`). The SELECT statement works in phpMyAdmin, but my PHP must have at least one error because I cannot get it to display. It might be related to how to reference the column from the joined table since without it, it works.

Here's the controller code:

```
//*******************  User role   ***********************//    
if(isset($_GET['role']))
{
    include '../includes/dbconnect-local.php';

    try 
    { 
        $sql = 'SELECT name, userid, email, roleid
            FROM user LEFT OUTER JOIN userrole
            ON user.id = userrole.userid
            ORDER BY name';
        $result = $db->query($sql);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        $error = 'Error fetching role data.';
        include 'error.html.php';
        exit();
    }

    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $roles[] = array(
            'name' => $row['name'],
            'userid' => $row['userid'],
            'email' => $row['email'],
            'roleid' => $row['roleid']
        );
    }

    include 'display_users_roles.html.php';

    header('Location: .');
    exit(); 

}
```

Here's the HTML (display_users_roles.html.php):

```
<?php
include '../includes/helpers.inc.php';
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>User roles</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>User roles</h1>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Role</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach($roles as $role): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($role['name']); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($role['userid']); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($role['email']); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($role['roleid']); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Where does the code currently stop at, `Error fetching role data`?

Comment: The `header('Location: .');` call strikes me as odd. Why is that there? If you have output buffering on, it may even be the cause of your problem, as it redirects you right after showing the page.

Comment: I found the problem. @Chris85, you're right about that also. The header needs deleted. However, before that the problem was that I neglected to include exit(); after the include. The code was advancing to the header just like it's supposed to. Funny how obedient  code can be!  It works now. Thanks for your consideration. I welcome any additional thoughts you might have regarding the code. Thanks for taking your time to review this!  The end should be:      include 'display_users_roles.html.php';
    exit();      
}

Comment: I'd recommend not using `query`. I always use `prepare` and `execute`. This way rather than hacking in escaping later prepared statements can always be added pretty easily.

Comment: @chris85 Thanks. The textbooks I read used query( ) to get a result set. Do you for security suggest $s = $db->prepare($sql), $s->execute( ) as a replacement?

Comment: Yes, have look at these two pages, they cover it pretty while. 1. http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php 2. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Thanks @chris85. Funny, I was just reading the first link before seeing your reply. Thanks for the help!